# What abilities will consume the Arcane Dynamo stacks?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

The [Arcane Dynamo](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/passive/arcane-dynamo) passive states:

> When you deal damage with a Signature spell you may gain a Flash of Insight. After 5 Flashes of Insight, your next non-Signature spell deals 75% additional damage.
>   The following skills are Signature spells:
>
> - Magic Missile
> - Shock Pulse
> - Spectral Blade
> - Electrocute

I've tried a few different abilities out (Blizzard and Disintegrate) - it doesn't seem like the stacks I've built up are being used and I'm not doing any additional damage.

Which abilities will and which abilities won't consume the Arcane Dynamo stacks?

Comment: I'd also like to know if you pop Archon after you have a full AD stack, does it affect the entire duration of Archon or just the first spell cast in that form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of your non-signature attacks that deal damage will consume the effect but you have to build up 5 stacks first.

It is an additional 75% so it will scale with the damage of the secondary attack used: the higher the damage of the spell used, the more noticeable it will be.

If you build up the 5 stacks then cast something with large amount of damage (non-channeled and non-DoT are the most noticable) like Arcane Orb you can see a large increase in the damage.

You can turn on the display of damage in the options screen if it isn't on and it will show the numbers.

**DoTs** -  It does work on DoTs (Venom Hydra, Blizzard, etc). Increases the amount of all ticks, not just the first one.

**Channels** - Works on channeled spells (Disintegrate, Ray of Frost, etc).  Increased for the whole duration of channeled spells.  Some
people have reported a drop off in damage after the first few seconds on Disintegrate but I haven't seen this.

**Archon** -  It does work but only increases the first attack and not the whole duration.

*This is based on my own testing and the general consensus for what I've read about it.*

> Edit: Here is a spreadsheet someone put together showing the damage increases for most of the spell/rune combos:
>   https://public.sheet.zoho.com/public/avunaos/arcane-dynamo?mode=html